# IIS Web.config Regex forward slash restraint

Tags: regex, iis, web-config, iis-8

I'm using web.config to rewrite URLs in IIS 8.5

This is my regex:

```
   match url="^((?:[a-z]{2}\/{1}){1,2})?listen$"
```

This will successfully match the following:

- en/gb/listen
- en/listen
- listen

However the part that I can't get to work is restraining the forward slashes in each optional group to a single character:

```
\/{1}
```

Interestingly this example does work on https://regex101.com/r/VNwejt/1

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try [`^(?:([a-z]{2})/(?:([a-z]*)/)?)?listen$`](https://regex101.com/r/qVSScR/1)

Comment: Thanks Wiktor. I would like en/gb//listen or en//gb/listen or en//listen to fail. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You may restrict the whole pattern using a negative lookahead at the start:

```
^(?!.*//)<PATTERN_GOES_HERE>
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qVSScR/5).

The `(?!.*//)` lookahead fails the match if there is a `//` substring anywhere on a line of text.

However, in this case, the lookahead is redundant as your consuming pattern does not allow 2 consecutive `//` anywhere in the string, `^(?!.*//)((?:[a-z]{2}/){1,2})?listen$`. Check the other options in your configuration file.

Comment: Apologies, I didn't make myself clear. I want two characters in both of my groups, that works fine. However I only want one forward slash. Whilst what has been suggested works in Regex, it doesn't work in my web.config file. Thanks again.

Comment: @Boomfelled OK, reverted the `{2}` limited quantifier. So, does it work like this now? Note there are now 2 capturing groups, so you will have to use two vars, `{R:1}` and `{R:2}`.

Comment: Thanks. However it's the forward slashes I'm interested in. Is there another way of writing \/{1} that passes / Thanks again

Comment: @Boomfelled Well, `{1}` is redundant, you may [remove it](https://regex101.com/r/qVSScR/4), and it will match the same. Sorry, but I thought you just wanted to capture the two values into different groups. What is the problem then? Your original regex does not match the strings you mentioned. Note that your original regex has no "optional groups".

Comment: Thanks. true enough {1} is redundant. Another way of asking this question is this: How do I NOT match '//', that's two forward slashes together, anywhere in the string?

Comment: Using `^(?!.*//)`.

Comment: Thanks for your help, all of your suggestions work in Regex but not in my web.config file, which was the initial problem. Thanks again.

Comment: @Boomfelled Then check your other settings. Are you sure there are no issues?